# c# immutable string constantly updated

Tags: c#, string, immutability

I've been doing some research on immutable strings and understand that the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created - instead, a new string is created each time.

I need an object that gets updated constantly - a "status" object of some sort that gets updated each time a timer thread makes its loop.

So my question is what can I use for such an object?

StringBuilder is good if there are a whole bunch of strings that need to be concatenated, but can it be efficiently used to change its value instead of append more values.

Can I use a custom enum?

How about a custom class with a string property with get set accessors, but then again the string property is immutable - or am I wrong?

Here is some sample code:

```
string status = "IDLE";

System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
System.Threading.TimerCallback callback = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(delegate
{
    status = getStatus();

    timer.Change(100, Timeout.Infinite);
});
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: In C#, unless you are building highly specialized software, are in a tight performancecritical loop or have measured and identified a bottleneck, you should never worry about garbage collection or memory footprints (except of course in blatantly obvious situations)

Comment: String objects are immutable, which means that you can't just replace some characters in them. That doesn't prevent you from assigning a different string to a variable, field or property though: `string a = "foo"; a = "bar"` is perfectly fine. `a` is a reference to a string, so you're really just 'pointing' it at a different string.

Comment: So, when a string is created, some memory is assigned to it, when the string gets changed, only the reference to the string changes, so the string keeps its place in memory (a new string with new memory is not created?)

Comment: The string does not get changed, that's the immutability point ! But the string that you are referencing is a new one. So you would end up with two strings in memory. But if you reuse the first string (the exact same sequence of characters), you will end up with the reference of the first string

Comment: @Sidewinder94 - If there are only 4 different statuses that can be assigned to the string, does that mean that only 4 strings will be created in memory and each time the string object gets changed, it will point to the relevant string in memory instead of creating a whole new string each time?

Comment: AFAIK, this should be how it is working.

Comment: Ah OK, I understand now.  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the string is immutable, what you store in property/attribute/field, is not the string itself but a reference to the string.

This means that you can replace the reference whenever you want.

To answer your question : you can perfectly use a string

Comment: Do you mean with a normal string or a string property in a custom class?

Comment: Both would work :) As kai/PieterWitvoet said, unless you're in a very specific context, you don't have to worry about creating a new string each time.